# Replace content block

Tags: draftjs

guys! Please help.

**What I want:** When starting from a new line a user types an URL and presses `Enter` I want to remove the block containing the URL and replace it with a custom `Entity`. Much like the Media example from the docs, but without the `Add image` button.

**What I tried:** (just a rough draft)

```
var mediaBlockRenderer = function(block) {
    if (block.getType() === 'atomic') {
        return {
            component: TestComponent,
            editable: false
        };
    }
    return null;
};

var TestComponent = function() {
    return <div className="test-component">TEST COMPONENT</div>;
};

onChange: function(editorState) {
        var currentKey = editorState.getSelection().getStartKey();
        var content = editorState.getCurrentContent();
        var selection = content.getSelectionBefore();
        var beforeKey = content.getKeyBefore(currentKey);
        var block = content.getBlockForKey(beforeKey);

        if (block && block.getText() === 'test') {
            console.log(block.getText());
            var len = block.getCharacterList().size;

            var newSelection = selection.merge({
                anchorOffset: 0,
                focusOffset: len
            });

            var newContent = Modifier.removeRange(content, newSelection, 'backward');
            editorState = EditorState.push(editorState, newContent, 'insert');
            var key = Entity.create('media', 'IMMUTABLE');
            editorState = AtomicBlockUtils.insertAtomicBlock(
                editorState,
                key,
                ' '
            );
            //editorState = EditorState.forceSelection(editorState, newContent.getSelectionBefore());

        }

        this.setState({
            editorState: editorState
        })
    }
```

It almost does what I want, but the inserted block can't be deleted by pressing backspace, the cursor just jumps to the top right corner.

**My question:** What is the recommended way of replacing blocks? How do you remove a block? And why my inserted block just won't get deleted?

Thanks!

Comment: Also interested in finding an answer to this question, having the same problem. I assume there's some extra magic that needs to be done apart from just EditorState.push, but not sure what it is.

Comment: have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up figuring out this by using `Modifier.replaceText` instead of `Modifier.removeRange`. What you can do is find the initial index of the URL and last index of the URL (let us call these `a` and `b` respectively), and we can do the following:

```
let newSelection = editorState.getSelection();
newSelection = newSelection.merge({
    anchorOffset: a,
    focusOffset: b
});

let newContent = Modifier.replaceText(editorState.getCurrentContent(), newSelection, "");
let newState = EditorState.push(editorState, newContent, 'insert-characters');

this.setState({ editorState: newState });
```

You can also define your `newSelection` however you want, so if you prefer to partition by `ContentBlocks` you can.